# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework for the first time, but it seems not working as expected.

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

public static class QueryClass
{
    public static void Query()
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbEntities())
        {
            DbSet<MyTable> set = context.Tables;
            var query = from val in set select value; 

        }
    }
}
```

On the query line (exactly the "set" variable is underlined in red) I get the error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'.'Select' not found. Missing a reference or
>   an using directive for 'System.Linq'

`MyDbEntities` is auto-generated by Entity Framework in a Database-First approach, `context.Tables` is a `DbSet`, so it should be able to use Linq, which has been added through the `using` directive. In order to avoid misurderstantings, within this class I find the following:

```cs
public virtual DbSet<MyTable> Tables { get; set; }
```

What am I missing in order to make the `select` work?

Thank you.

Comment: does your project have a reference System.Core?

Comment: @Krishna yes it does

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you will need to add reference to System.Data.Linq

System.Data.Linq is LINQ-SQL specific (DataContext, etc)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;

public static class QueryClass
{
    public static void Query()
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbEntities())
        {

            IQueryable<MyTable> qTable= from t in context.Tables
                                        select t; // can you confirm if your context has Tables or MyTables?
            Console.WriteLine("Table Names:");
            foreach (var t in qTable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.Name);//put the relevant property instead of Name
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I referenced _System.Data.Linq_ and added it throught _using_ directive, but it is still giving me that problem

Comment: it does not work. Directly using from [...] gives me the error_Could not find Type or Namespace 'from'_ while prepending a var x = from [...] gives me the original error of this post.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i was doing this outside VS. Please try again. Also check if your context is having MyTables or Tables as the table db set name

Comment: I've updated my question to explain what Tables and MyTable are.
Anyways now I get something interesting: VS seemed not recognizing IQueryable, altough System.Linq is properly loaded. Restarted (once again) VS and now that annoying bug in OP has disappeared, completely random. Seriously, no clue what's going on.

Comment: :) is "set" not a reserved keyword. Please try another variable name

Comment: In my case I needed to reference System.Linq

Comment: The reference to System.Data.Linq should be done when using Linq2SQL, in all other cases set reference to System.Linq.