# LINQ to SQL - 'Select' not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have been looking to solve this for hours with no luck.

I have a very simple scenario - I am trying the following in LINQ-to-SQL

```
 var qry = (from row 
   in DBConnect.SEARCHhash("test", "1234")  
    select row);
```

Where the `SEARCHhash` is a stored procedure - Unfortunately, I can't even put `.ToList()` at the end because IntelliSense shows the following error

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'void'.  'Select' not found.

All my other stored procedures work fine, just this one doesn't work.

Then I remember that when I dragged and dropped the stored procedure to Designer I got the following warning

> The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected. Set the return type for each stored procedure in the Properties window.

[image]

So, I opened the properties and clicked on dropdown and only available option was int(int32) so selected int

[image]

But now then I started getting the following error

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'.  'Select' not found

The following is the code from Designer

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.SEARCHhash")]
        public int SEARCHhash([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Keywords", DbType="VarChar(540)")] string keywords, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="UserId", DbType="NVarChar(128)")] string userId)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), keywords, userId);
            return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

I also started comparing my stored procedures and I noticed that this stored procedure has `JOIN` in it and of course it is using `FREETEXT'

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[SEARCHMLinksData].PageID, 
    [dbo].[SEARCHMLinksData].PageTitle, 
    [dbo].[SEARCHMLinksData].PageDescription, 
    [dbo].[SEARCHMLinksData].PageType
FROM 
    [dbo].[SEARCHMLinksData] 
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[SEARCHMLinksTags] ON [SEARCHMLinksData].PageID = [SEARCHMLinksTags].PageID
WHERE 
    (FREETEXT([SEARCHMLinksData].*, @Keywords) OR  
     FREETEXT([SEARCHMLinksTags].*,@Keywords) ) 
    AND
    ([SEARCHMLinksData].UserID = @UserId OR [SEARCHMLinksTags].[user_id] = @UserId)
```

Any idea or help will be appreciated

Cheers

In addition, I tried so many things including the following 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1542/using-stored-procedures-with-linq-to-sql/
[The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035669/the-return-types-for-the-following-stored-procedures-could-not-be-detected)
[Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241541/could-not-find-an-implementation-of-the-query-pattern-for-source-type-system-da)

Comment: Can you see if `import System.Linq;` is added in your cs file?

Comment: Hi, yes `using System.Linq; 
using System.Xml.Linq; 
using System.Data.Linq;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if anyone is looking for the solution

It is not possible to use `FREETEXT` in LINQ and that was the reason I created the *Stored Procedure* although in my case it seems like it was not possible to use the *Stored Procedure* either for some reason (i don't know why) Although the solution I found was to

> **create a function and call the function using LINQ**

It works for me now

One thing I had to do in the *function* though that - Instead of using

```
(FREETEXT([SEARCHMLinksData].*,@Keywords)
```

I had to use

```
(FREETEXT([SEARCHMLinksData].Title,[SEARCHMLinksData].Description,@Keywords)
```

Means, list all the columns getting indexed by their [names] as it didn't take wildcard

Why all this? I have no idea but that's the only solution I could found

Hope this helps someone.